# throwing exception as part of a sequence in moqu

Tags: c#, moq

I'm checking a retry operation that I created.
The function that is being called i.e. "run" can throw an exception and in that case it would be called again.
I'm trying to run a test that first calls a function and then throws exception and on the 2nd execution, it returns a result.
Here's how I built it.

```
_mock.SetupSequence(mock => mock.run())
    .Throws(new Exception())
    .Returns("");
```

I don't see the exception been thrown for some reason

Comment: if the SUT throws exception then how can it return a value? unless something being return from catch block

Comment: Can you include more code (e.g. the code that is being tested, more of the test code, etc.)? That may help in providing useful answers.

Comment: The test checks a retry operstion. The whole purpose of what I want to acheive is to test that im the first call to a function it throws an exception and after it's being called again, it returns a value. I use setupSequance because I understood it does that. (Updated origins post)

Comment: The posted code is syntactically incorrect. Can you update it to show closer to what you're actually doing?

Comment: @Avi the moq itself allows you to throw exception within the sequence. Could you explain what exactly is your problem and share also the retry code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

When you throw a Exception, the Exception de-facto becomes the return value (even if it is not de-jure).

When the Compiler is tasked to automatically implementing a Interface function, it will just write `throw new NotImplementedException();` It does not mater what the return type of the function is, the compiler recognizes it as "all paths return a value" and will compile it just fine.

Another way to look at it, is that the Exception line will jump to the next catch block that cares for it (while still calling Finally code along the way).